# Using Knockout, why isn't my array of computed observables updating?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table of values where I need a total on the row and column. The row total is a simple `computed observable` and works fine, but the array of `computed observables` used to store the column totals does not update.

In my example, when changing values in the grid, the monthTotals array does not update.

Why aren't these changes updating? Should I be doing this differently?

http://jsfiddle.net/MYMtH/5/

Comment: What should the rows be showing in the html?

Comment: 6000 initially, but then the value should update as you change values in the grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of monthNumber in `val += parseFloat(self.resourceCategories[i].monthAmounts[monthNumber].amount());` is always set to its last value (11), because the computed evaluates after the fact, and uses the last value set for monthNumber.

Here is an updated jsfiddle with the computed changed to a regular function that takes in the month to compute:

http://jsfiddle.net/MYMtH/7/

Answer (score 1):

Tuan is correct as to why your current use of monthNumber is causing problems.  If you want to retain your current style, you can encapsulate the MonthTotal in a separate object which would retain the month number for when the computed recalculates:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/MYMtH/8/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I looked at your code some more, and am wondering what is wrong. In the JS fiddle this is what I see:

[image]

What should it be showing?

You should take a look at

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid

Comment: it initializes ok, but if you change values in the grid, the column total does not update.